# How to save page settings for the next session?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, session-state, html-input

With my Greasemonkey script, I've added a checkbox. My idea is that if the checkbox is true do something, but if it is false do nothing.

I also want the checkbox to remember the user's last choice, so that if the user closes the webpage or browser, when he returns the checkbox is again true/false.

For example:

```
$('input[name=check0]').click(function(){
    $('#shoutbox_b').click();
});
```

In this example, I want `check0` to be always true. But, when I reload the page it is false until I click the checkbox again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GM_setValue()` or `localStorage` to save the input state between page loads.

Here is **a complete Greasemonkey script**, using jQuery, that shows the process.  It is for normal, *static* pages.  (For AJAX-driven pages you would also use `waitForKeyElements`):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Save checkbox state between page visits
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @grant    unsafeWindow
// ==/UserScript==

//-- Get saved state:
var chk0wasChked    = (localStorage.getItem ('check0_state')  ==  "true");

//-- Get current state:
var chk0isChked     = $('input[name=check0]').prop ('checked');

/*-- If the states don't match, click the checkbox to synch them up.
    We need a small delay to avoid race conditions.
*/
setTimeout (setThenMonitorCheckboxState, 333);

function setThenMonitorCheckboxState () {
    if (chk0wasChked != chk0isChked) {
        unsafeWindow.$('input[name=check0]').click ();
    }

    //-- *After* the initial set, monitor & save any future state changes:
    $('input[name=check0]').click ( function () {
        var chk0isChked = $('input[name=check0]').prop ('checked');

        localStorage.setItem ('check0_state', chk0isChked);
    } );
}
```

---

Note:  The question was not clear.  If the original click handler for `input[name=check0]` was set by the **target page**. Use the code as above.

But, if the original click handler for `input[name=check0]` was set by the 
**Greasemonkey script**, then change `unsafeWindow.$` to just `$`.

Answer (score 0):

Using localStorage is your best option, even more than a cookie.
localStorage is well supported in all browsers and most mobile devices